# Why does console.trace() show a growing stack trace when using event listeners with { once: true } option?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, callstack, removeeventlistener

I have this inline js code.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", foo, { once: true });

function foo() {
  btn.addEventListener("click", bar, { once: true });
  console.log("Foo called");
  console.trace();
}

function bar() {
  btn.addEventListener("click", buz, { once: true });
  console.log("Bar called");
  console.trace();
}

function buz() {
  btn.addEventListener("click", foo, { once: true });
  console.log("Buz called");
  console.trace();
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

The output I received was a bit difficult to understand. After few button clicks, it shows something like this.

```
Foo called index.html:11:17
foo file:///.../index.html:12
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)

Bar called index.html:16:17
bar file:///.../index.html:17
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
foo file:///.../index.html:10
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)

Buz called index.html:21:17
buz file:///.../index.html:22
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
bar file:///.../index.html:15
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
foo file:///.../index.html:10
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
```

As you can see, at the "Bar called index.html:16:17" line there seems to be two stack frames. And at the "Buz called" there are three stack frames. So my question is why this happen?

I expected it to produce something like this.

```
Foo called index.html:11:17
foo file:///.../index.html:12
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)

Bar called index.html:16:17
bar file:///.../index.html:17
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)

Buz called index.html:21:17
buz file:///.../index.html:22
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/so-q-77552461-dzj6zg) ([console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEjnh.png)).

Comment: @InSync That's strange. When I ran it in firefox it gave me ([this](https://imgur.com/gfsPmWH)) . Now when I run it on chrome, it gives me the expected output like in your screenshot.

Comment: Looks like an [async stack trace](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/async-call-stack/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this note at the top of the documentation page:

> **Note:** In some browsers, `console.trace()` may also output the sequence of calls and asynchronous events leading to the current `console.trace()` which are not on the call stack — to help identify the origin of the current event evaluation loop.
>
> — [`console.trace()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/trace_static)

This is not a bug of either Chrome or Firefox, since the specs made it clear that the trace is implementation-specific:

> #### 1.1.8. trace(...data)
>
> 1. Let *trace* be some implementation-specific, potentially-interactive representation of the callstack from where this function was called.
> 2. Optionally, let *formattedData* be the result of [Formatter](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter)(*data*), and incorporate *formattedData* as a label for *trace*.
> 3. Perform [Printer](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer)("trace", « *trace* »).
>
> — [Console Standard | WHATWG](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#trace)